# Get local json file using request-promise

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm making a node/express app and am querying a test json file using [npm request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise). Node is spitting out the following error in my `<title>` tags:

Error: `<title>Invalid URI "../testJSON/user.json"</title>`

I believe my pathing is correct, so am unsure why it's an invalid URI.

I've also provided the entire project path URI with the same issue:

```
return rp('http://localhost:3000/app/testJSON/user.json');
```

**User Service:**

```
module.exports = {

getUserData: function(){
        var options = {
            uri : '../testJSON/user.json',
            method : 'GET'
        }
        return rp(options);
    }
}
```

**User Controller:**

```
var User = require('../services/User.service');
User.getUserData()
    .then(function(data){
        res.render('pages/userdata', {
            title: 'User Data',
            content: JSON.parse(data)
        });
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
```

**Pathing:**

User Service: projectroot/app/services/userService.js

User json file: projectroot/app/testJSON/user.json

---

Update: trying with node `fs` to fetch local file

```
fs = require('fs');

module.exports.index = function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile('../testJSON/user.json', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
      if (err) {
          return console.log(err);
      }
      res.render('pages/user', {
          title: 'User',
          content: JSON.parse(data)
      });
  });
  ...
```

Node error:

> { [Error: ENOENT, open '../testJSON/user.json'] errno: -2, code:
>   'ENOENT', path: '../testJSON/user.json' }

Comment: `request` is an _HTTP_ request library, not a local file reader library. If you want to read local files, you should use [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).

Comment: @robertklep then why am I able to use angular `$http` service to make requests to local json files?

Comment: Because Angular runs in a browser, not in Node.

Comment: @robertklep okay I tried with fs. Getting `ENOENT` error. See update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relative paths (starting with `../` or `./`) are relative to the *current working directory*. If you want to read a file relative to the current JS source file, you need to prefix the path with `__dirname`, which is the directory where the current JS source file resides:

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/../testJSON/user.json', ...);
```

Or the more elaborate (but probably more correct) way:

```
var path = require('path);
...
fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, '../testJSON/user.json'), ...);
```